# Under axiom $C_1$, $X$ is Hausdorff iff every compact subset is closed

Tags: general-topology

**Problem** Suppose $X$ satisfies $C_1$ axiom, i.e., $X$ has countable local basis. Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff *iff* every compact subset of $X$ is closed.

I wonder if there is an answer to this question on Stack Exchange. If not, it would be appreciated if anyone could more or less hint me. Thanks!

Comment: You should say what the $C1$ axiom is- there's a lot of conflicting terminology out there.

Comment: @Vercingetorix It means the first countable axiom in general topology(point set topology), as stated after ‘i.e.’ in the question:)

Comment: Oh, whoops lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is Hausdorff. Fix any compact set $K \subseteq X$ and some $x \in X \setminus K$. Then for every $y \in K$ there are disjoint open sets $U_y, V_y$ such that $x \in U_y$ and $y \in V_y$. Clearly the $V_y$ form an open cover for $K$ so there is some finite subcover $V_{y_1}, \cdots, V_{y_n}$. Then it is not hard to see that $x \in \cap_{i \leq n} U_{y_i}$ and moreover that $\cap_{i \leq n} U_{y_i}$ is disjoint from $K$. This implies closedness as $x$ was arbitrary. Notice we didn't use first countability (the more common term for $C_1$) here.

Now suppose $X$ is first countable and every compact set is closed. Then given any $x, y \in X$, take the local bases $\{U_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{V_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ for $x$ and $y$ respectively. As usual we may assume that $U_{n + 1} \subseteq U_n$ and similar for $V_n$, for all $n$. Suppose for contradiction that they *couldn't* be separated by an open set, then we would have a $z_n \in U_n \cap V_n$ for each $n$. Then consider $K = \{z_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{x\}$.

Notice that this is compact: For any open cover, take a $U_n$ contained in whichever open set of the open cover contains $x$, call it, $U$. So $x \in U_n \subseteq U$. Then due to $U_m \subseteq U_n$, $z_m \in U_n$ for $m \geq n$ and the remaining finitely many points can be added individually with finitely many sets. But this is *not* closed since $y \not \in K$. So we have constructed a compact but not closed subset from violating the Hausdorffness of $X$.